# How to get file author name and last major version in sharepoint hosted app?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jsom, sharepoint-hosted-app, sp.js

I am developing SharePoint Hosted App to get specific file's all properties like author, created time, modified time, last major version etc.

I didn't get the author name of file and I got `SPUser` object in console. How can I get user name from `SPUser` object?

Also for version I got `SPFileVersionCollection` object, how to get last major version from that?

Here my developed code

```
 function getFileInfo(SiteRelativeUrl, FileUrl)
{
    var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);        
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl + SiteRelativeUrl);
    console.log(hostweburl + SiteRelativeUrl);
    var web = appContextSite.get_web();
    var file = web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl(FileUrl);
    context.load(file);
    context.executeQueryAsync(function () 
    {    
        console.log(file.get_title());
        console.log(file.get_timeCreated());
        console.log(file.get_timeLastModified());
        console.log(file.get_modifiedBy());
        console.log(file.get_versions());
        console.log(file.get_author().get_userId());
    }, function (sender, args) {
        console.log('failed. Message:' + args.get_message());
    });
}
    $(document).ready(function () {        
    getFileInfo('/', '/Shared%20Documents/try_getalllistwidhiddent.txt');
});

function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
//var strParams = "";    
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
    var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
    if (singleParam[0] == param) {
        return singleParam[1];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can get user details by its id like following:

```
function getUserById(userId) {

    var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPAppWebUrl'));
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));
    var context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    var appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl + SiteRelativeUrl);
    var web = appContextSite.get_web();
    var user = web.get_siteUsers().getById(userId);
    context.load(user);

    context.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        console.log(user.get_title());
    }, function() {

    });
}
```

You don't have to find last major version from `SPFileVersionCollection`. `SP.File` has property named `get_majorVersion ()`. See in *[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246003.aspx)*

Just use following

```
console.log(file.get_majorVersion());
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the full name of the SP.User object use:

```
.get_lookupValue()
```

I am not sure how to get the last version from version collection, but have a look at [THIS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245447.aspx#properties).

Unfortunately there's no method or property in SP.FileVersionCollection object to get the last major version, but I think you can somehow loop through the versions?